# best way to pass an array of object with activeroute - Angular

Tags: json, angular, angular-routing, angular-router

I'm trying to pass an array of objects through activeroute. When I pass it to the next page I get [object Object]. I saw a question on Stackoverflow where they use JSON.stringify but that didn't work for me. Or is it better to use **application providers** instead of queryparams.

**TS of page sending the data**

```
criteriaList: ShipmentLookupCriteria[] = [];

    navigateTo() {
        const navigationExtras: NavigationExtras = {
          queryParams: {
            criteriaList: this.criteriaList
          }
        };

        this.router.navigate(['/lookup/results'], navigationExtras);
    }
```

**TS of page receiving the data**

```
 this.sub = this.route.queryParams.subscribe(params => {
      console.log(params.criteriaList);
 });
```

**ShipmentLookUpCriteria model**

```
import { EquipReferenceTuple } from './equip-reference-tuple.model';
export class ShipmentLookupCriteria {
  terminal: string;
  equipReferenceList: EquipReferenceTuple[];
  constructor(terminal: string, equipReferenceList: EquipReferenceTuple[]) {
    this.terminal = terminal;
    this.equipReferenceList = equipReferenceList;
  }
}
```

**UPDATE**
I decided to start with something simple. So I create an array of objects with dummy data.

```
navigateTo() {
    const navigationExtras: NavigationExtras = {
      queryParams: {
        criteriaList: [{ name: 1, age: 1 }, { name: 2, age: 2 }]
      }
    };

    this.router.navigate(['lookup/results'], navigationExtras);
  }
```

**PAGE RECEIVING THE PARAMS**

```
 this.route.queryParams.subscribe(params => {
      console.log(params.criteriaList[0]);
 });
```

RETURNS = `[object Object]` If I do again JSON.stringify it shows it as string `"[object Object]"`. if I do `params.criteriaList[0].name` returns `undefined`

Comment: Use `resolve` which maps to `data` not params for data structures

Comment: @AluanHaddad Promise.resolve(params.criteriaList)?  returns ["[object Object]", "[object Object]" which takes me back to my same issue

Comment: Not `Promise.resolve`. I mean `resolve` in your route config. If you want it in your url, then you need to serialize it

Answer (score 1):

You can simply pass,

```
this.router.navigate(['/lookup/results'], {queryParams: {criteriaList: this.criteriaList }});
```

and access it using

```
this.sub = this.route.snapshot.queryParamMap.get('criteriaList');
```

Comment: your answer on the other stackoverflow questions is the one that was using JSON.stringify I wished it work for me like it work for that other person lol. let me try this answer

Comment: I'm getting "Argument of type '{ criteriaList: ShipmentLookupCriteria[]; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'NavigationExtras'.
  Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'criteriaList' does not exist in type 'NavigationExtras'."

Comment: ohh wait. You just updated your answer. Let me try that

Comment: I did this  `console.log(this.route.snapshot.queryParamMap.get('criteriaList'));` and  I'm still getting this `[object Object]`

Comment: alright now you can access console.log(this.route.snapshot.queryParamMap.get('criteriaList').whatever you need);

Comment: it says on typescript ` Property 'equipReferenceList' does not exist on type 'string'` this is what I did `console.log(this.route.snapshot.queryParamMap.get('criteriaList')[0].equipReferenceList);` i did the [0] since it's an array of objects

Comment: can you tell me what do you get when you do console.log(JSON.stringify(this.route.snapshot.queryParamMap.get('criteriaList')));

Comment: "[object Object]"

Comment: "[object Object]"  as string*

Comment: Check my updated questions. I tried to start with something basic and I'm getting the same. If you need me to create a stackbliz I can do so

Comment: I think that each criterion must be a property of `queryParams` for this to work: `queryParams: {name: 1, age: 1}`. I could be wrong but encoding a nested structure seems like it would result in a really nasty mangled url if it works at all

Comment: @AluanHaddad I have done a lot of research and nobody seems to have done what I'm trying to do. I read somewhere on github that it not possible yet. The easiest way to do it would be thought an application provider. http://www.angulartutorial.net/2017/12/3-simple-ways-to-share-data-through.html

Comment: Well yes, shared state can accomplish this but has drawbacks especially in the context of routing.

Comment: @AluanHaddad for your help and Sajeetharan help. I wish there was a way to accomplish this